# I need a name search function to insert 7 rows for each missing agent

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Morning I use excel 2010, I grab data everyday on sales rep stats, some are off or on vacation  from time to time - what I need is a formula to search for each of the reps in order and insert 7 rows for each missing rep. say I have tim tod jim dave / so if tod was missing it would be tim (insert 7 rows) jim dave or if tod and jim were missing it would be tim (insert 14 rows) dave.

make sense? is it even possible and can I pick where to insert rows?

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible to do this with VBA, but I don't know of a built-in worksheet function in Excel that would do this without calling into VBA.

See [Getting Started with VBA in Excel 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737.aspx) if you are new to VBA. You may think "oooo, programming, scary" if you do not have a background in programming; but it is designed so that working professionals can learn and make use of VBA to automate and improve their everyday workflow.